# Как сделать эффект при наведении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Имеются изображения, при наведении на каждое из изображений, должно происходить их затемнение и появление текста. То есть навел на первую картинку - первая картинка затемнилась и появился текст.
Пытался через :hover::after - в итоге просто глючит.

```css
.block-six {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block-six-cont {
  display: flex;
}

.block-six-photo img {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#block-six-cont-one {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div calss="block-six">
  <div class="block-six-cont">
    <div id="block-six-cont-one">
      <div class="block-six-photo">
        <img src="img6.jpg" width="100%" center />
      </div>
      <div class="block-six-photo">
        <img src="images/img5.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="block-six-cont-one">
      <div class="block-six-photo">
        <img src="images/img7.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="block-six-photo">
        <img src="images/img4.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.block-six-photo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.block-six-img {
  width: 100%;  
  display: block;
}

.block-six-text {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;  
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.block-six-photo:hover .block-six-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-six-photo">
  <img class="block-six-img" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" alt="">
  <div class="block-six-text">Text text text</div>
</div>
<div class="block-six-photo">
  <img class="block-six-img" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" alt="">
  <div class="block-six-text">Text text text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Через `:hover:after` можно сделать так:

```css
.block-six {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block-six-cont {
  display: flex;
}

.block-six-photo img {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#block-six-cont-one {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block-six-photo {
  position: relative;
}

.block-six-photo:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #7c00ff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.block-six-photo:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: 1;
}
```

```html
<div calss="block-six">
  <div class="block-six-cont">
    <div id="block-six-cont-one">
      <div class="block-six-photo" data-text="img6">
        <img src="img6.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="block-six-photo" data-text="img5">
        <img src="images/img5.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="block-six-cont-one">
      <div class="block-six-photo" data-text="img7">
        <img src="images/img7.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="block-six-photo" data-text="img4">
        <img src="images/img4.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```